# MVC Form jumping to top of page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

On my MVC Form on error I wanted to have focus on the ValidationSummary but the page jumps to the top. The ValidationSummary is at the bottom. Can I keep it at the bottom of the page and stop the jumping up ?

```
@using (Html.BeginFormSitefinity("Create", "Form", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Form" }))
    
 



 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "alert alert-danger" })
    </div>
    </div>  
                                    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary px-4 float-right">Submit</button>
```

Comment: https://forums.asp.net/t/1545969.aspx?How+To+prevent+a+page+with+ValidationSummary+to+jump+to+top+position+after+failed+validation+

Comment: Is there a MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback setting in MVC?>